# why uniform initiallizer list feature does not work in VS2012 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I am unable to use uniform initializer in VS 2012 in C++.

what could be the possible reason of this? Is there any problem in using uniform initializer feature in C++ program?

Comment: It takes time and work to implement it.

Comment: VS2012 does not support list-initialization (i.e. the core language feature). VS2013 does support it, but still has some serious bugs relating to list-initialization.

Comment: There is a support matrix on MSDN somewhere.

Comment: @TimSeguine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: @dyp, thanks, I think it should be helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uniform initialization and `initializer_list`s were only added to VS 2012 in the  [November 2012 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx?Redirected=true). Note that this was only an addition of the language level feature and the `initializer_list` header to VS. Meaning you could use them for your code but the standard containers didn't make use of them yet.

As @dyp notes in comments VS 2013 does supposedly fully support them, there are some bugs in the implementation though.

Comment: @rubenvb they _are_ getting better. Visual Studio moves slowly because it is an enterprise product, not because of malice or ineptitude.

Comment: @Tim True enough, but they are still lagging behind pretty much all competition when it comes to language/library support. And the fact updates are all $$$ makes "bug fixes" kind of malicious.